# How to make background-color go over the width of parent div?

Tags: css, width, html

I'm creating a music player.
In order to make it easier to download songs i want the background to change for every second song to a darker color
since it is PHP I want to link to the actual page and not the script
http://thestartpage.comeze.com/music/ 
When you get to the page click on for example Eminem (4 songs)
As you can see I have succeeded in making every second song a different style.
But I want the background color to go all the way to the download link

Here is my CSS

```
#songs span {
color:#000000;
text-shadow:none;
padding-left:10px;
padding:10px;
margin-left:-24px;
width:100%;
/*left:325px; */
background-color:#FFFFFF;
/*right:0px; */
}
#songs span #download {
position:absolute;
float:left;
right:25px;
margin-top:-5px;
}
#songs span:hover {
cursor:pointer;
margin-left:0px;
}
```

The parent div have no set width, it just have the position set to absolute and the top, bottom, left and right determines the width and height of it.

If you need any more information just let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: EM.. Server is busy ?)

Comment: I have no problems reaching the server

Comment: Can I just mention that, while I'm not a lawyer, if the user can really download those songs by clicking the links on your site, you're in danger (unless you have an appropriate license) of being guilty of copyright infringement (depending on your local laws). *Also* don't add 'solved' (or any variants) to your question's title; if the problem is solved by another person's answer then accept that answer (click the tick-mark beside it). If you solved the problem yourself, add that solution as an answer and, after a two-day (enforced) period, accept that answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas I wont keep the website up, I will have it on my localhost for personal use and it was just a tempoary domain so you had something to view while helping me resolve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width on the `#songs` element.  The `span` tags will expand to fill their parent.  You may want to consider using `div` tags instead of the span tags.